# MySQL many-to-many full combination of possibilities

Tags: mysql

What I'm wanting is every possible combination from Users.id and Groups.id with GroupMembership.id null when there is no entry in the GroupMembership table & not null when there is...

So for example say there's 3 groups, 3 users. User 1 is in group 1, user 2 is in groups 1 & 2, user 3 is in no groups, group 3 has no users. I'm looking to retrieve a listing that looks a bit like this:

```
--> user1
U.id = 1
G.id = 1
Gm.id = 1

U.id = 1
G.id = 2
Gm.id = (null - I.e there isn't an entry in the table that intersects this U.id & G.id combo)

U.id = 1
G.id = 3
Gm.id = (null - I.e there isn't an entry in the table that intersects this U.id & G.id combo)

--> user2
U.id = 2
G.id = 1
Gm.id = 2

U.id = 2
G.id = 2
Gm.id = 3

U.id = 2
G.id = 3
Gm.id = (null - I.e there isn't an entry in the table that intersects this U.id & G.id combo)

--> user3
U.id = 3
G.id = 1
Gm.id = (null - I.e there isn't an entry in the table that intersects this U.id & G.id combo)

U.id = 3
G.id = 2
Gm.id = (null - I.e there isn't an entry in the table that intersects this U.id & G.id combo)

U.id = 3
G.id = 3
Gm.id = (null - I.e there isn't an entry in the table that intersects this U.id & G.id combo)
```

I can get all users and possible gms like this:

`SELECT t1.id, t2.idGroupMembership
    FROM auth.users t1
    LEFT JOIN AcmeCo.GroupMembership t2 ON t1.id = t2.idUser
    WHERE t1.staff = 1
    ORDER BY id, idGroup`

However if I try to slip Groups into the equation like so...:

`SELECT t1.email, t2.idGroupMembership, t3.idGroup
    FROM auth.users t1
    LEFT JOIN AcmeCo.GroupMembership t2 ON t1.id = t2.idUser
    LEFT JOIN AcmeCo.Groups t3 ON t3.idGroup = t2.idGroup
    WHERE t1.staff = 1`

... I don't get the full set of groups back - it doesn't show records which don't intersect. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CROSS JOIN. This worked for me using sqlite and your test data.

```
    SELECT U.id, G.id, Gm.id
    FROM Users U CROSS JOIN Groups G
    LEFT JOIN GroupMembership Gm
    ON U.id = Gm.idUser AND G.id = Gm.idGroup;
```

Result:

```
    1|1|1
    1|2|
    1|3|
    2|1|2
    2|2|3
    2|3|
    3|1|
    3|2|
    3|3|
```

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is standard SQL and should be available in all databases.

Comment: Great, I know there'd be a simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get all possible combinations beween two tables you should not LEFT JOIN them. This query wil do the trick:

```
SELECT t1.email, t2.idGroup
  FROM auth.users AS t1, AcmeCo.Groups t2
```

Now, to select the group membership ID do this:

```
SELECT t1.email, t2.idGroup,
       (SELECT idGroupMembership FROM AcmeCo.GroupMembership WHERE idUser=t1.id AND idGroup=t2.idGroup) AS idGroupMembership
  FROM auth.users AS t1, AcmeCo.Groups t2
  ORDER BY t1.id, t2.idGroup
```